# Flutter TextField triggering rebuild whenever i select or deselect the TextField

Tags: flutter, dart, textfield

#### Setup

I am trying to pop a page onto the stack that displays a simple search page. I have a TextField and a back button. If the user taps the back button I pop off the page. If the user searches for something the widget rebuilds and displays the search results. This functionality works great right now.

#### Problem

My problem is that whenever the TextField is selected or deselected (The keyboard pops up or closes) the whole widget rebuilds. This triggers the Future again even tho the search term has changed and I see a progress wheel until my future returns. How can I stop this from happening?

I looked at other forms and they suggested `MediaQuery.of(context)` is causing the rebuilds however I use it quite a bit in my code and would prefer not having to remove it. So I am looking for an alternative solution to prevent the rebuilds every time I select or deselect the TextField.

Thanks for the help!

```
\\Call to push and see the stateful Widget
Navigator.push(
 context,
 MaterialPageRoute(
   builder: (context) => SearchRoomBuilder(
     key: const Key('SearchRoomBuilder'),
     searchTerm: value,
   ),
 ),
);
    

class SearchRoomBuilder extends StatefulWidget {
  final String searchTerm;
  const SearchRoomBuilder({super.key, required this.searchTerm});

  @override
  State<SearchRoomBuilder> createState() =>
      _SearchRoomBuilderState();
}

class _SearchRoomBuilderState
    extends State<SearchRoomBuilder>
    with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
  late final TextEditingController _textController;
  final double _borderRadius = 20.0;
  late String searchTerm;

  static final GlobalKey<FormFieldState> _searchFieldKey =
      GlobalKey<FormFieldState>();

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _textController = TextEditingController(text: widget.searchTerm);
    searchTerm = widget.searchTerm;
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _textController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);

    final theme = Theme.of(context);
    print('$searchTerm');
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).viewPadding.top,
          ),
          Card(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 0),
            elevation: theme.appBarTheme.elevation,
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0.0),
            ),
            child: Container(
              height: 60,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              color: theme.appBarTheme.backgroundColor,
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  InkWell(
                    child: Container(
                      width: 60,
                      height: 60,
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8),
                      child: Icon(
                        Icons.arrow_back_rounded,
                        color: theme.appBarTheme.foregroundColor,
                      ),
                    ),
                    onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                      child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0),
                    child: TextField(
                      key: _searchFieldKey,
                      controller: _textController,
                      enableSuggestions: false,
                      autocorrect: false,
                      textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                      textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.center,
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                      style: theme.textTheme.titleMedium,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        prefixIcon: Icon(
                          Icons.search,
                          color:
                              theme.colorScheme.onBackground.withOpacity(0.5),
                        ),
                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                        hintText: 'Search',
                        hintStyle: theme.textTheme.titleMedium?.apply(
                            color: theme.colorScheme.onBackground
                                .withOpacity(0.5)),
                      ),
                      onSubmitted: (value) {
                        setState(() {
                          searchTerm = value;
                          _textController.text = value;
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                  )),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: FutureBuilder(
              key: Key('$searchTerm'),
              future: MManager().searchQuery(searchTerm),
              builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Product>?> snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                  if (snapshot.hasError ||
                      ((snapshot.data?.length ?? -1) <= 0) ||
                      snapshot.data == null) {
                    //If no results found for any reason display no results message
                    //CODE THAT DISPLAYS NO RESULT MESSAGE HERE
                  } else {
                    return ListView.separated(
                      itemCount: snapshot.data?.length ?? 0,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
                      separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return SizedBox(height: 5);
                      },
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        if (snapshot.data?[index] == null) {
                          return const SizedBox.shrink();
                        }
                        return DisplayListTile(
                          product: snapshot.data![index],
                          index: index,
                        );
                      },
                    );
                  }
                } else {
                  //While waiting for respons
                  return Center(
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                    color: theme.colorScheme.primary,
                  ));
                }
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It must rebuild to allow space for the keyboard.  Your widget should survive repeated build() 60 times per second, so apparently you have something defined in build() that you need to lift to State.

Comment: In my scaffold, I set ```resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,```  so the keyboard shouldn't affect the screen. I also can't seem to find anything in my build that's changing between states.

Comment: Ahh, why are you doing this: `    super.build(context);`

Comment: Please check if onSubmitted: (value) {
                        setState(() {
                          searchTerm = value;
                          _textController.text = value;
                        });
                      },
if this line is causing issue as you are calling setstate here

Comment: ```super.build(context);``` Is used to implement the AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin. This was my attempt to stop the rebuilding or at the very least stop the future from retriggering.

Comment: Even if I fully remove the ```onSubmitted``` permit the rebuilds are still triggered whenever I tap on the textField or minimize the keyboard. It rebuilds 3 times according to the print statement in the build function.